# Where did the old C# class wizards go?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have Visual Studios 2010 Pro

I read that apparently the older versions of Visual Studios use to have a Wizard for adding classes in C#. It allowed all sorts of things like baseclass and interface methods.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288077(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These features are now all in the editor itself.

Adding a base class is trivial - just add

```
: YourBaseClass
```

To the type. Likewise interfaces, noting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to resolve namespaces automatically. Right-Click on the interface name to add the interface methods.

Re overrides; type `override` and it gives you a list of overrides left. Selecting one then  <kbd>tab</kbd> provides the signature and a default implementation.

So essentially, all these features are now in the editor - available **all** the time rather than just when adding the class.

Comment: Not quite what I was expecting.  I was hoping for something similar to Eclipse. But I thinking this way is better. Having these features built into Intellisense makes more 'sense.'

Answer (score 1):

You still have the Wizards, maybe a bit different than what you are looking for. I'll add the steps shortly.

Okay, somewhat of a let-down as this doesn't include all of the inheritance features you described. This is how I've displayed the 'Wizard':

[image]

or ...

[image]

and *gasp* ...

[image]

Hhmmm ... not exactly a head turner.

I cannot find anything specifically as a Visual Studio add on yet. It would be nice to have something that would auto-generate some of that recursive code. I think that may be what the point of VS Templates are - although not as dynamic as a wizard would be.

[*Edit*]
@Marc Gravell is right: the functions of the wizard are replaced by Intelli-Sense. I *do* think that even with Intelli-Sense, it would be nice to have the New Type Generator include options for inheritance, selecting public static as in a 'checked' listbox rather than a single descriptor. It is a bit lack-luster and I would probably use it if it provided more flexibility. While Intelli-Sense does replace the **need** for a wizard, I believe it would have been better to keep the old (but improved) Type Generator to reduce confusion.[*/*]

Comment: I think the OP wants to know where to find the wizard as well.

Comment: @Filip I think he's looking in VS at the moment to give instructions

Answer (score 1):

When you open a C++ Project, there you'll have the Class Wizard. In a C# Project i didn't ever see such a wizard. I creat my classes with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>